# Pass Terraform Output from One Module to Another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-security-group

I am having trouble passing the output of one module into another module in Terraform. In my main.tf, I am creating a security group. I want to pass the id of this security group to the vpc_security_group_ids of my EC2 instance creation. Here is my code:

```
    ├── main.tf
    ├── modules
    │   ├── security-groups
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   │   └── variables.tf
    │   └── vm-deploy
    │       ├── main.tf
    │       ├── output.tf
    │       └── variables.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

main.tf

```
    module "security-groups" {
      source= "./modules/security-groups"
    
      for_each= var.security-groups
    
      name= each.value.name
      description= each.value.description
      vpc_id= data.aws_vpc.vpc.id
    }
    
    module "vm-deploy" {
      source= "./modules/vm-deploy"
    
      for_each= var.instances
    
      ami= each.value.ami
      iam_instance_role= each.value.iam_instance_role
      instance_type= each.value.instance_type
      key_name= each.value.key_name
      private_ip= each.value.private_ip
      subnet_id= each.value.subnet_id
      user_data= each.value.user_data
      vpc_security_group_ids= [module.security-groups.id]
      kms_key_id= each.value.kms_key_id
      root_size= each.value.root_size
    }
```

modules/security-groups/main.tf:

```
    resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
      name= var.name
      description   = var.description
      vpc_id= var.vpc_id
      tags= var.tags
```

modules/security-groups/outputs.tf:

```
    output "id" {
      value= aws_security_group.security_group.id
    }
```

modules/vm-deploy/main.tf:

```
    resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
        ami= var.ami
        iam_instance_profile= var.iam_instance_role
        instance_type= var.instance_type
        key_name= var.key_name
        private_ip= var.private_ip
        subnet_id= var.subnet_id
        user_data= var.user_data
        vpc_security_group_ids= var.security_group_ids
        root_block_device {
          delete_on_termination = false
          encrypted= true
          kms_key_id= var.kms_key_id
          volume_size= var.root_size
          volume_type= "gp2"
        }
      }
```

When I execute terraform plan, I get the following error:

```
    │   on main.tf line 45, in module "vm-deploy":
    │   45:   vpc_security_group_ids= [module.security-groups.id]
    │     ├────────────────
    │     │ module.security-groups is object with 1 attribute "sg-default"
    │ 
    │ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create both modules with the `for_each` loop. Thus, this line `vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security-groups.id]` in your root module is incorrect, because `module.security-groups` is not a single object, but a list of objects.

If you intend to pass all security group ids created by `module.security-groups`, you should use a [splat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat), e.g. `vpc_security_group_ids = module.security-groups[*].id`. Or, if you want to select one SG module per instance, then you should access it like so: `vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security-groups["sg-default"].id]`, where `"sg-default"` is a key that comes from `var.security-groups` which you use in `module.security-groups`'s `for_each`. If you don't understand the last example, check Terraform [for_each docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Anton. I tried both variations per your suggestion.
`vpc_security_group_ids= module.security-groups["*"].id`, and `vpc_security_group_ids= module.security-groups["name"].id` both error with Invalid Index. module.security-groups is object with 1 attribute "sg-default". The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.`

Comment: @virtualramblings try [*] without quotes or `module.security-groups["sg-default"].id`.

Comment: Hey Anton. Putting the sg-default in quotes worked! Thank you for your help.